# would anyone be able to point me in the right direction with math in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to work out a problem where I have to create a program that will call days of the week, print out day preceding and after selected day, as well as return the day that is added, so if a user selects Sunday, the program will return Saturday as the day before, Monday as the day after and the day x amount added into console. I am completely lost and could use any advice offered... the code I have so far is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public final class MurphyW8Day {
    private int murphingDay;
    private String namedDay;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (namedDay);
    }
    public void setDay(int murphingDay) {
        if (murphingDay == 0)
            namedDay = "Sun";
        if (murphingDay == 1)
            namedDay = "Mon";
        if (murphingDay == 2)
            namedDay = "Tue";
        if (murphingDay == 3)
            namedDay = "Wed";
        if (murphingDay == 4)
            namedDay = "Thur";
        if (murphingDay == 5)
            namedDay = "Fri";
        if (murphingDay == 6)
            namedDay = "Sat";
    }
    public MurphyW8Day setNameDay(String murphingDay) {
        murphingDay = namedDay;
        return this;
    }
    public void printDay() {
        System.out.println(namedDay);
    }
    //I believe my issue is somewhere between here :

    public void previousDay() {
        murphingDay = (murphingDay - 1);
        setDay(murphingDay);
        printDay();
    }
    public void nextDay() {
        murphingDay = (murphingDay + 1) % 7;
        setDay(murphingDay);
        printDay();
    }

    //And Here:

    public void calculateDay() {
        int calc;
        int dayAdd;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Enter number of days to add: ");
        calc = scanner.nextInt();

        dayAdd = murphingDay + (calc);

        murphingDay = dayAdd % 7;

        setDay(murphingDay);
        printDay();
    }
    public MurphyW8Day() {
        setDay(0);
    }
    public MurphyW8Day(int murphingDay) {
        setDay(murphingDay);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("What is your initial day?\nSunday\t\t=\t0\nMonday\t\t=\t1\nTuesday\t\t=\t2\nWednesday\t=\t3\nThursday\t=\t4\nFriday\t\t=\t5\nSaturday\t=\t6");
        System.out.print("Enter the number:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        MurphyW8Day myDay = new MurphyW8Day(x);
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("The day of the week is: ");
        myDay.printDay();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("The previous day is: ");
        myDay.previousDay();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("The next day is: ");
        myDay.nextDay();

        System.out.println();

        myDay.calculateDay();
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
```

the output in console is:

```
run:
What is your initial day?
Sunday      =   0
Monday      =   1
Tuesday     =   2
Wednesday   =   3
Thursday    =   4
Friday      =   5
Saturday    =   6
Enter the number:5
The day of the week is: Fri
The previous day is: Fri
The next day is: Sun
Enter number of days to add: 
5
Fri
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

I cant figure out what I am missing, am going by my book and oracle website... please shed some light on this I just want to finish this program so I can go on a much deserved vacation from school for a week. lol

Thank you in advance for any help offered.

Comment: So you have this code. What is it _actually_ doing?

Comment: console output when ran results in: run:
What is your initial day?
Sunday  = 0
Monday  = 1
Tuesday  = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday = 4
Friday  = 5
Saturday = 6
Enter the number:5

The day of the week is: Fri

The previous day is: Fri

The next day is: Sun

Enter number of days to add: 
5
Fri

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: Your `setDay(int)` method doesn't actually set murphingDay?

Comment: when commented out returns null for day of week current, prior and after

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of suggestions:

1. Your class `MurphyW8Day` has two fields that are equivalent in the sense that one can be straightforwardly calculated from the other.  I would remove one of them, and add a method to calculate it as needed.  My preference would be to remove `namedDay`, as calculating the day name from the day number is pretty trivial, and in fact you have pretty much the required code in `setDay`.
2. Following on from (1), you have two setter methods, `setDay` and `setNamedDay`.  One of these could be removed, and my suggestion would be to remove the one that corresponds to the field removed in (1).
3. Finally, make sure the remaining setter (eg `setDay`) sets the field in the class.  It doesn't at the moment, and I think this is the major source of your current issues.

The actual math looks correct to me.

As an aside, you may want to consider separating out the calculations from the input and printing, so that you can use them independently.